# What is the most efficient way to retrieve a line from a file containing multiple sorted runs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, full-text-search

As the title suggests, I have a file containing vocabularies (each on a single line) sorted in A-Z and I would like to retrieve all vocabularies with a given prefix. **The problem is that the file contains more than one A-Z sorted runs**, each represents a different language. It's impossible to do pre-processing to the data file and since you cannot determine the length of a sorted run, I cannot think of a better way than simply traversing the whole file and compare on the run which takes O(n). Is it possible to achieve O(logN) with this weirdly sorted file?

Comment: Can you determine a *minimum* length of a sorted run?  If you can, then you can use that to skip around to identify sorted runs without looking at most lines.

Comment: @btilly I can't assume anything because all I have is just a data file and the design should tolerate anything.

Comment: Can you count the number of characters per line? (the literal length of each dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing better than a full-file scan is possible if neither an index or altering the file is allowed when the runs are of an unknown size.

However, if the start-end offset of each run is known then a full file scan would only need to be done once and binary searching could be employed in each section - for ~`O(k lg (n/k))` after the index build. The start-end offsets are trivially available for the duration of the program and could be stored in a cache file as needed.

If the start-end index also contained relevant top-level prefix such as starting letter then the initial search space could be further divided and avoid a few seeks.

If the file is small, and the memory sufficient, it may also be an option to keep everything in an in-memory structure. It may also be worthwhile looking into an existing store like SQLite; although pre-processing was said to not be feasible.

Comment: The file is large so in-memory sorting isn't an option. And yes it would be nice to have the offset but unfortunately I don't have them ready. Maybe a full-scan is inevitable.

Comment: @r0dney The full-scan only needs to be done once, so if a query is numerous times within the same process (or a cache/index file is created) then it will definitely pay off.

Comment: I've thought about the same thing but just kept wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: @r0dney: This is the best solution. Indexes rock. (How many languages can you have? Surely a list of start positions will be a trivial amount of space.)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the k lists into 1 sorted list (k way merge), which is a one time o(n*lg(k)) task. After that you will be able to run in o(log n).